# Control Names Changed After Copy / Paste

Tags: vb.net, copy, controls, paste

I had controls in a tab and then decided to add another tab control on that current tab.

Therefore I copied all the controls in the first tab to put them in the nested tab. Now my buttons went from being:

```
Private Sub Quit_Button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles
```

To

```
Private Sub Quit_Button_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles
```

I have an insane amount of controls on that tab and none of them work because of this ... All their names stayed the same as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the copy / paste, my code was transformed into:

```
Private Sub btnAddNote_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
```

Instead of:

```
Private Sub btnAddNote_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddNote.Click
```

I was only missing the Handles and the event ... For some reason it deletes it when we copy & paste.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using MS Visual Studio, which will rename controls and methods using the convention you noticed. That is of course if you are copying/pasting controls using the GUI designer.

Why not go into the code (look for the method InitializeComponent in your form) and change the "parent" control that contains the controls you want to be on a different tab?

For example, starting with the following snippet:

```
Me.TabControl1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TabControl()
Me.TabPage1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage()
Me.TabPage2 = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage()
Me.MyButton = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
Me.TabPage1.Controls.Add(Me.MyButton)
```

Change that last line to:

```
Me.TabPage2.Controls.Add(Me.MyButton)
```

... and your button (and it's associated event handling methods, etc.) will now be contained by the 2nd tab.

Comment: Right, I noticed that. Also you're right I am using Visual Studio, I apologize for not mentioning that. I encountered the issue that you talked about and changed it - but I figured out the real cause which I'll be posting as an answer in a few seconds